# Mobile test automation tools recommended in industry

Tags: testing, mobile, automation

Please suggest the recommended open source tools for mobile automation testing which supports ios and android?

Answer (score 2):

For Android I would recommend

[UI automator framework](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html) and [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Monkeytalk. Try it-
http://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk

It has very good online documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use appium: http://appium.io/ which is open source, cross-platform test automation tool for native, hybrid and mobile web apps

Answer (score 0):

Selenium webdriver is good for Android as well as iphone.
On iphone it works slowly but accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

Appium is really coming up in these days to capture Android and IPhone mobile automation market though it has some limitation for Android automation like support for Toast messages is missing etc.

Robotium can be a good choice for Android automation as it comes with a flexible API with a large number of utility methods included inside.

If you looking to automation Android or IPhone Web applications, Selenium Android Driver and IPhone driver can be a good choice.

Comment: Is there any tool available which produces automation tests reports also? Mean if they have passed or failed etc?

Comment: With **Robotium** we can Integrate **Android-Junit-Report** which produces XML Based reports. **Android JUnit Report:** http://zutubi.com/source/projects/android-junit-report/. 

With **Appium** also there are ways to generate HTML and XML reports

Answer (score 0):

Today you have plenty of approaches, you can use Appium as everyone said, here you have the advantage that is similar to Selenium and same code can run for Android and iOS. It's black box testing and it's slow, 8 times more slow than native approaches.

So, you have native approaches, Espresso for Android and XcuiTest for iOS. This approaches are faster that Appium and are white or grey box testing. The disadvantage is that you need to code Java/Kotlin and Swift for the tests and maybe you testers have no skills in this languages but developers can help.